# Join two data frame and update one data frame records with another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So i have two data frame .
Data Frame 1 like this :

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877341|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877346|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877341|   138|        2|       1|  I|!||
|4295877341|   141|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877341|   143|        2|       1|  I|!||
|4295877341|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||
| 123456789|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||
| 809580109|   145|       9|        9|  I|!||
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

DataFrame2 is like below

```
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId_1|Sequence_1|Action_1|
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|4295877343|   149|         15|         2|    I|!||
|4295877341|   136|       null|      null|    I|!||
| 123456789|   145|         14|         1|    D|!||
|4295877341|   138|         11|        22|    I|!||
|4295877341|   141|         10|         1|    I|!||
|4295877341|   143|          1|         1|    I|!||
| 809580109|   145|       NULL|      NULL|    I|!||
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Now i have to join both data frame update data frame 1 column  with matching records with data frame 2 .

Now key in both data frame is OrgId and ItemId.

So the expected output should be .

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877346|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877341|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||
|4295877343|   149|       15|       2|  I|!||
|4295877341|   136|     null|    null|  I|!||
|4295877341|   138|       11|      22|  I|!||
|4295877341|   141|       10|       1|  I|!||
|4295877341|   143|        1|       1|  I|!||
| 809580109|   145|       9|        9|  I|!||
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

So i need to update data frame 1 with data frame 2 records .
If records in data frame 1 is not found in 2 then also we need to retain that records .
If any new records are found in dataframe 2 then that records needs to added in the output

Here is what i am doing ..

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("OrgId", "ItemId"), "outer")
  .select($"OrgId", $"ItemId",$"segmentId_1",$"Sequence_1",$"Action_1")
  .filter(!$"Action_1".contains("D"))
    df3.show()
```

But i am getting below output .

```
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId_1|Sequence_1|Action_1|
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|4295877343|   149|         15|         2|    I|!||
|4295877341|   136|       null|      null|    I|!||
|4295877341|   138|         11|        22|    I|!||
|4295877341|   141|         10|         1|    I|!||
|4295877341|   143|          1|         1|    I|!||
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

I am not getting `4295877346|   136|        4|       1|  I|!|` record from data frame 1 ...

left_outer gives me below output

```
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId_1|Sequence_1|Action_1|
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|4295877341|   136|       null|      null|    I|!||
|4295877341|   138|         11|        22|    I|!||
|4295877341|   141|         10|         1|    I|!||
|4295877341|   143|          1|         1|    I|!||
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain first whats your mistake.

if you only join as below

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("OrgId", "ItemId"), "outer")
df3.show()
```

You will get

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|segmentId_1|Sequence_1|Action_1|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|4295877346|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||       null|      null|    null|
|4295877341|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||       null|      null|    null|
|4295877343|   149|     null|    null|  null|         15|         2|    I|!||
|4295877341|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||       null|      null|    I|!||
| 123456789|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||         14|         1|    D|!||
|4295877341|   138|        2|       1|  I|!||         11|        22|    I|!||
|4295877341|   141|        4|       1|  I|!||         10|         1|    I|!||
|4295877341|   143|        2|       1|  I|!||          1|         1|    I|!||
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

It is full evident that the `filter` in your code is filtering the `null` as well in `Action_1` column

So the working code for you is to change the `null` values that you get after you `join` to valid data from other table where the data is present.

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("OrgId", "ItemId"), "outer")
  .withColumn("segmentId_1", when($"segmentId_1".isNotNull, $"segmentId_1").otherwise($"segmentId"))
  .withColumn("Sequence_1", when($"Sequence_1".isNotNull, $"Sequence_1").otherwise($"Sequence"))
  .withColumn("Action_1", when($"Action_1".isNotNull, $"Action_1").otherwise($"Action"))
  .select($"OrgId", $"ItemId",$"segmentId_1",$"Sequence_1",$"Action_1")
  .filter(!$"Action_1".contains("D") )
df3.show()
```

you should be getting the desired output as

```
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId_1|Sequence_1|Action_1|
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|4295877346|   136|          4|         1|    I|!||
|4295877341|   145|         14|         1|    I|!||
|4295877343|   149|         15|         2|    I|!||
|4295877341|   136|       null|      null|    I|!||
|4295877341|   138|         11|        22|    I|!||
|4295877341|   141|         10|         1|    I|!||
|4295877341|   143|          1|         1|    I|!||
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: There is slight change in the records ...If suppose for one specific columns if we get null value like last records in the DF1 and update for DF1 last records in in DF2 is null then we have to retain the DF1 value only for that columns ..How can we do that ?

Comment: sorry to tell you @Anupam, I didn't understand clearly your requirement. Can you explain a little bit more.

Comment: So there are some columns which are optional which means when that column value is null in that case we dont have to update with the DF2 column value ..null as string

Comment: modify the when condition according to your needs as i have done in my answer above

Comment: Hi...I know it is silly question to ask ..But suppose i have null in the place of primary key ..For example null value in the place of `ItemId` in that case how can i solve this problem ..I know primary key can not be null but there is situation where i will get part of the primary key as null ...

Comment: Can i create separate question for this?

Comment: which dataframe is it? first or the second?

Comment: if you have null then it will join with nulls of other dataframe. There won't be any issue. did you get one?

Comment: Oh ok yes i will be getting null so just thought to ask ... I will just try to join with null and then will see ..If you are confirming i think then it will work

Comment: if you encounter any issues do let me know or you can ask another question. But confirm it yourself by testing on test data. good luck. :)

Comment: Hello sir my colleague  created separate question with an example .Please have a look ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269172/get-latest-records-in-a-data-frame-based-on-time-stamp-with-condition

Answer (score 0):

Try left-outer instead of outer:

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("OrgId", "ItemId"), "left_outer")
  .select($"OrgId", $"ItemId",$"segmentId_1",$"Sequence_1",$"Action_1")
  .filter(!$"Action_1".contains("D"))
    df3.show()
```

Left outer should retain all non matched in the left.

A nice tutorial [here](http://kirillpavlov.com/blog/2016/04/23/beyond-traditional-join-with-apache-spark/).