# How to use window specification and join condition per column values?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my DF1

```
OrganizationId|^|AnnualPeriodId|^|InterimPeriodId|^|InterimNumber|^|FFAction
4295858898|^|204|^|205|^|1|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|204|^|208|^|2|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|204|^|209|^|2|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|204|^|211|^|3|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|204|^|212|^|3|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|204|^|214|^|4|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|204|^|215|^|4|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|206|^|207|^|1|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|206|^|210|^|2|^|I|!|
4295858898|^|206|^|213|^|3|^|I|!|
```

Here is my DF2

```
   DataPartition|^|PartitionYear|^|TimeStamp|^|OrganizationId|^|AnnualPeriodId|^|InterimPeriodId|^|InterimNumber|^|FFAction|!|
  SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917595|^|4295858941|^|24|^|25|^|4|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917596|^|4295858941|^|24|^|25|^|4|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917597|^|4295858941|^|30|^|31|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917598|^|4295858941|^|30|^|31|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917599|^|4295858941|^|30|^|32|^|1|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917600|^|4295858941|^|30|^|32|^|1|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917601|^|4295858941|^|24|^|33|^|3|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917602|^|4295858941|^|24|^|33|^|3|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917603|^|4295858941|^|24|^|34|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917604|^|4295858941|^|24|^|34|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917605|^|4295858941|^|1|^|2|^|4|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917606|^|4295858941|^|1|^|3|^|4|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917607|^|4295858941|^|5|^|6|^|4|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917608|^|4295858941|^|5|^|7|^|4|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917609|^|4295858941|^|12|^|10|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917610|^|4295858941|^|12|^|11|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917611|^|4295858941|^|1|^|13|^|1|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2003|^|1511224917612|^|4295858941|^|12|^|14|^|1|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917613|^|4295858941|^|5|^|15|^|3|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917614|^|4295858941|^|5|^|16|^|3|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917615|^|4295858941|^|1|^|17|^|3|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917616|^|4295858941|^|1|^|18|^|3|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917617|^|4295858941|^|5|^|19|^|1|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917618|^|4295858941|^|5|^|20|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2001|^|1511224917619|^|4295858941|^|5|^|21|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917620|^|4295858941|^|1|^|22|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2002|^|1511224917621|^|4295858941|^|1|^|23|^|2|^|O|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2016|^|1511224917622|^|4295858941|^|35|^|36|^|1|^|I|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2016|^|1511224917642|^|4295858941|^|null|^|35|^|null|^|D|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2016|^|1511224917643|^|4295858941|^|null|^|36|^|null|^|D|!|
SelfSourcedPublic|^|2016|^|1511224917644|^|4295858941|^|null|^|37|^|null|^|D|!|
```

I want to implement join based on the value of the column.

This is what I am trying to achieve in Spark-Scala for example but don't know how to implement it

**If the `FFAction_1 =I` in the DF2 then below condition**

(join and partitionBy on three columns `"OrganizationId", "AnnualPeriodId","InterimPeriodId"`)

```scala
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationId", "AnnualPeriodId","InterimPeriodId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc) 

val latestForEachKey = df2result.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank", "TimeStamp")

val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinalWithYear.join(latestForEachKey, Seq("OrganizationId","AnnualPeriodId","InterimPeriodId"), "outer")

.select($"OrganizationId", $"AnnualPeriodId",$"InterimPeriodId",
   when($"FFAction_1".isNotNull, concat(col("FFAction_1"), 
   lit("|!|"))).otherwise(concat(col("FFAction"), lit("|!|"))).as("FFAction"))
  .filter(!$"FFAction".contains("D"))
```

**If the `FFAction_1 =O or D` then below condition**

(join and partitionBy  on two columns `"OrganizationId","InterimPeriodId"`)

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationId","InterimPeriodId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc) 

val latestForEachKey = df2result.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank", "TimeStamp")

val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinalWithYear.join(latestForEachKey, Seq("OrganizationId","AnnualPeriodId","InterimPeriodId"), "outer")

.select($"OrganizationId", $"AnnualPeriodId",$"InterimPeriodId",
   when($"FFAction_1".isNotNull, concat(col("FFAction_1"), 
   lit("|!|"))).otherwise(concat(col("FFAction"), lit("|!|"))).as("FFAction"))
   .filter(!$"FFAction".contains("D"))
```

Below is my full code

```scala
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
    import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

val get_cus_val = spark.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))
val get_cus_YearPartition = spark.udf.register("get_cus_YearPartition", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(4))

val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/Interim2Annual/MAIN")
val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("OrganizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("OrganizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)

val schemaHeader = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "."), StringType)).toSeq)
val dataHeader = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("OrganizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schemaHeader)

val df1resultFinal=data.withColumn("DataPartition", get_cus_val(input_file_name))
val df1resultFinalWithYear=df1resultFinal.withColumn("PartitionYear", get_cus_YearPartition(input_file_name))


//Loading Incremental 

val rdd1 = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/Interim2Annual/INCR")
val header1 = rdd1.filter(_.contains("OrganizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema1 = StructType(header1.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1.filter(!_.contains("OrganizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema1)


 //--- filtering only the latest from incremental ---
 
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
    val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationId","AnnualPeriodId","InterimPeriodId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc)
    val latestForEachKey1 = data1.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank")


    val windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationId","InterimPeriodId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc)
    val latestForEachKey = latestForEachKey1.withColumn("tobefiltered", first("FFAction|!|").over(windowSpec2))
      .filter($"tobefiltered" === "I|!|" || $"tobefiltered" === "O|!|" || ($"tobefiltered" === "D|!|" && $"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|"))
      .drop("tobefiltered", "TimeStamp")

//--- separating the incremental df for insert, deletion and overwrite ---

    //--- insert rows are selected ---
    //insert a row if I is detected and if O is found then first delete and then insert
    
    val insertdf = latestForEachKey.filter($"FFAction|!|" === "I|!|" || $"FFAction|!|" === "O|!|").select(df1resultFinalWithYear.schema.fieldNames.map(col):_*)

    //------------------deleted rows with primary key  "OrganizationId", "InterimPeriodId"------------------
    // delete rows from parent if both D or O is found in incremental
    val deletedf = latestForEachKey.filter($"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|" || $"FFAction|!|" === "O|!|").select($"OrganizationId", $"InterimPeriodId", lit("delete").as("Delete"))

    //join by two primary keys for deletion and delete from the parent dataframe
    val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinalWithYear.join(deletedf, Seq("OrganizationId", "InterimPeriodId"), "left").filter($"Delete".isNull).drop("Delete")

val dfToSave=dfMainOutput.union(insertdf).withColumn("FFAction|!|", when($"FFAction|!|" === "O|!|" || $"FFAction|!|" === "I|!|", lit("I|!|")))

val dfMainOutputFinal = dfToSave.na.fill("").select($"DataPartition", $"PartitionYear",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").filter(_ != "PartitionYear").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))

val headerColumn = dataHeader.columns.toSeq

val header = headerColumn.mkString("", "|^|", "|!|").dropRight(3)

val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)


    dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition","PartitionYear")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("quote", "\u0000")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/Interim2Annual/output")

   val FFRowCount =dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.groupBy("DataPartition","PartitionYear").count
  
  FFRowCount.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "FFFileType")
  .option("rowTag", "FFPhysicalFile")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/Interim2Annual/Descr")
```

Comment: your code needs a lot of reviews and has a lot of unwanted transformation. I will have to go line by line logics. And you will have to help me understand that

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER** Somehow this and the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47387390/1305344) I've just answered seem duplicates so one is going to get marked as such soon or we find out the difference between them and the disclaimer goes away. Time will tell.

---

Given the requirement to select the final window specification and join condition based on the values of `FFAction_1` column, I'd do `filter` first and decide what window aggregation and join to use.

```
val df1 = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  option("sep", "|").
  csv("df1.csv").
  select("OrganizationId", "AnnualPeriodId", "InterimPeriodId", "InterimNumber", "FFAction")
scala> df1.show
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
|OrganizationId|AnnualPeriodId|InterimPeriodId|InterimNumber|FFAction|
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
|    4295858898|           204|            205|            1|       I|
|    4295858898|           204|            208|            2|       I|
|    4295858898|           204|            209|            2|       I|
|    4295858898|           204|            211|            3|       I|
|    4295858898|           204|            212|            3|       I|
|    4295858898|           204|            214|            4|       I|
|    4295858898|           204|            215|            4|       I|
|    4295858898|           206|            207|            1|       I|
|    4295858898|           206|            210|            2|       I|
|    4295858898|           206|            213|            3|       I|
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
```

The right-hand side of the join is fairly similar in "shape".

```
val df2 = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  option("sep", "|").
  csv("df2.csv").
  select("DataPartition_1", "PartitionYear_1", "TimeStamp", "OrganizationId", "AnnualPeriodId", "InterimPeriodId", "InterimNumber_1", "FFAction_1")
scala> df2.show
+-----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
|  DataPartition_1|PartitionYear_1|    TimeStamp|OrganizationId|AnnualPeriodId|InterimPeriodId|InterimNumber_1|FFAction_1|
+-----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2002|1510725106270|    4295858941|            24|             25|              4|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2002|1510725106271|    4295858941|            24|             25|              5|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2003|1510725106272|    4295858941|            30|             31|              2|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2003|1510725106273|    4295858941|            30|             31|              3|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2001|1510725106293|    4295858941|             5|             20|              2|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2001|1510725106294|    4295858941|             5|             21|              3|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2002|1510725106295|    4295858941|             1|             22|              4|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2002|1510725106296|    4295858941|             1|             23|              5|         O|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2016|1510725106297|    4295858941|            35|             36|              1|         I|
|SelfSourcedPublic|           2016|1510725106297|    4295858941|            35|             36|              1|         D|
+-----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

With the above datasets, I'd `filter` out to see if there's at least one `I` in `df2` in `FFAction_1` column and select the correct window specification and join condition.

The trick is to use `join` operator followed by `where` (or `filter`) operator so you can decide on what join condition to use.

```
val noIs = df2.filter($"FFAction_1" === "I").take(1).isEmpty
val (windowSpec, joinCond) = if (noIs) {
  (windowSpecForOs, joinForOs) 
} else {
  (windowSpecForIs, joinForIs)
}
val latestForEachKey = df2result.withColumn("rank", rank() over windowSpec)
val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinalWithYear.join(latestForEachKey).where(joinCond)
```

Comment: @eliasah looks like so, but I'm unsure yet. Let's wait till they approve one as the OPs are quite responsive. For the time being I think they're different as one uses windows and join while the other just window specs (no join condition). In that sense they're different and require that the join condition be inside `where` as a Column expression. Hold on with closing either if you don't mind.

Comment: I was wondering if the input data is separated by `|^|` and if only `|` is used as a separator, wouldn't it be a problem when dataframe is created as there would duplicate column names with `^` as column names?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Remove `select` and see yourself :) Been there done that.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I got `Reference '^' is ambiguous, could be: ^#34, ^#36, ^#38, ^#40, ^#42, ^#44, ^#46.;` error, thats why I asked.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski i am just testing all my scenario ...Thanks you so much ..I will respond back

Comment: @JacekLaskowski can you please sample full code.Scala syntax is my weakness.. I have updated my full code ...Can you please edit it once ..