# How to use different window specification per column values?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

This is my partitionBy condition which i need to change based on the column value from the data frame .

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("col1", "clo2","clo3").orderBy($"Col5".desc)
```

Now if the value of the one of the column (col6) in data frame is I then above condition .

But when the value of the column(col6) changes O then below condition

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("col1","clo3").orderBy($"Col5".desc)
```

How can i implement it in the spark data frame .

So it is like for each record it will check whether col6 is I or O based on that partitionBy condition will be applied

Comment: Wouldn't `filter` before applying the window aggregation make sense?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski one example please so filter also should be based on condition ? ...we can not remove the column that will be required later in other transformation

Comment: Can you please give an example ? From the top of my head, I have an idea but I need more details to write it down !

Comment: @eliasah here is the details question which my colleague with bounty on it ..Please have a look ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292886/implementing-outer-join-in-spark-data-frame-with-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirement to select the final window specification based on the values of `col6` column, I'd do `filter` first followed by the final window aggregation.

```
scala> dataset.show
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col5|col6|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   0|   0|   0|   0|   I| // <-- triggers 3 columns to use
|   0|   0|   0|   0|   O| // <-- the aggregation should use just 2 columns
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

With the above dataset, I'd `filter` out to see if there's at least one `I` in `col6` and apply the window specification.

```
val windowSpecForIs = Window.partitionBy("col1", "clo2","clo3").orderBy($"Col5".desc)
val windowSpecForOs = Window.partitionBy("col1","clo3").orderBy($"Col5".desc)

val noIs = dataset.filter($"col6" === "I").take(1).isEmpty
val windowSpec = if (noIs) windowSpecForOs else windowSpecForIs
```

Comment: thank you ...I will try this answer and will respond you

Comment: At least we have something to discuss and improve upon. Can't wait to hear from you.

Comment: @Anupam, I would do so too. To separate the original dataframe and apply the logics separately and finally union them. :)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski testing all my scenario ...Will respond back with details ..Thank you so much